# Angular UI Map loading

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui

I have tried to follow the https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map guide to integrate google maps into my project, but I don't quite understand where I'm going going wrong. I also get a strange error.

I load the following scripts:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-map/ui-map.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-map/ui-map.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false&callback=onGoogleReady"></script>
```

The callback throws an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null on line 11

My app modules

```
 var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'AppControllers',
    'AppFactories',
    'ngSanitize',
    'AppDirectives',
    'ngResource',
    'ngAnimate',
    'mgcrea.ngStrap',
    'ui.map' <---- angular map ui
  ]);
```

html from my view

```
 <section id="map" style="height:400px;width:400px;">
    <div ui-map="myMap" ui-options="mapOptions" class="map-canvas"></div>
    </section>
```

I don't know where to place the

```
function onGoogleReady() {
  console.log('Google maps api initialized.');
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('map'), ['app.ui-map']);
}
```

bit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there is element with id `map` in DOM when you call `angular.bootstrap` ?

Comment: yes it does exist. I have added the html in the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to get it to work by just loading the Google API in first instead of last.

Comment: Did you met any problems when using ui-map with angular strap? I'm considering it too.